# Django generic UpdateView. How to check credential

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to edit a post and save it.

So far I have managed to do this as well as implementing a check to see whether the user is logged in or not.

However, I can't seem to find how to verify that the user has the right to do so.

Here is my code:

```
class PostUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','body','page','category']
    template_name = 'post_update.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PostUpdate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner_user = self.request.user
        return super(PostUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

In my Post model, I have a field called "owner_user" which holds a User as foreign key:

```
owner_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to be able to use the `pk` variable that I have in my *urls.py*

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit',
    PostUpdate.as_view(),
    name='PostUpdate'),
```

and check it do something like this:

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=pk)
if post.owner_user == request.user:
    #Show edit page
else:
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

How would I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a get_object method and check the user is the owner of the object there like so:

```
class PostUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','body','page','category']
    template_name = 'post_update.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PostUpdate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(PostUpdate, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        if not obj.owner_user == self.request.user:
            raise Http404
        return obj

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner_user = self.request.user
        return super(PostUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: No problem, check out [link](http://ccbv.co.uk/) for future work with class-based views in Django, great resource that complements the docs well